# Why is there a flicker when swapping an inner Panel?

Tags: java, awt, panel, flicker

Just a small problem. Currently coding a Java project for a Dell Axim X51 with J9 installed. The problem is to do with my interface, for different screens I simply swap a nested Panel (note its running 1.4 and NO swing), so remove(panel) - add(newPanel). The problem is when it swaps the panels the time taken to do so is visible and flickers.

I guess this is a run of the mill refresh/buffering problem but I have tried overriding paint and update so am fresh out of ideas. Also if someone has a particular dislike to this method of navigation (swapping panels within a frame) can you suggest a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to implement double-buffering:

[Double buffer in standard Java AWT](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/javadoublebuffer.aspx)

Alternatively, when you "swap" an old panel for a new panel, set the new panel to be hidden initially, then make it visible only after it has been add()ed to its parent container.

Comment: Sorted, set visible AFTER the add. Cheers :)